# Redirect automatically all links from one basic-URL to one other URL (HTML, JS)

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, redirect

First: English is not my motherlanguage, so I hope I am able to describe my problem though in a way you understand it and maybe even give me a solution.

PROBLEM:
My old affiliate partner did not longer work so thousands of these product-links are also not longer working. To avoid replace them all with my hands, I think there must be a way with JavaScript (or anything like that, unfortunately I am a coding-noob) to redirect all of these links to ONE new link (in my case the amazon-startpage).

EXAMPLE:
Each links from "http://www.example-domain.xy" (like example-domain.xy/product-z1 , example-domain.xy/product-z2 and so on) shall be redirected to "https://www.amazon.com/start-page-with-myRef"

SOLUTION:
So which code is neccessary to do this? I use Wordpress, it may help you. I guess, some JS in the functions.php could handle this.

Thank you honestly a lot!

Comment: Maybe a possible solution is to change directly the links on the database, using a custom query.

Comment: You can do HTTP 301 (permanent redirect) in server configuration.

Comment: @phanter They're affiliate links - OP doesn't have access to the server they point at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the JavaScript you would use:

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var href = links[i].href; 
    if (href.startsWith("http://www.example-domain.xy"))
        links[i].href = "https://www.amazon.com/start-page-with-myRef";
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.example-domain.xy/product-a">Product-A</a><br/>
<a href="http://www.example-domain.xy/product-b">Product-B</a><br/>
<a href="http://www.different-domain.com/product-c">Product-C</a><br/>
```

Comment: That looks pretty good! So I have to copy your code into the functions.php? Thanks a lot my friend!

Comment: You should be able to add the script in the head section of your header.php file using 

<script type="text/javascript">
    COPY CODE HERE
</script>  

Here's some helpful reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work :(

I copied the code from VAR to } into the given section (without the a hrefs)

Comment: Did you change the URL on the "if" line to match the actual domain you are trying to replace?  You put this somewhere in the <head></head> section of your header.php template file, between the meta tags and the style sheet link, surrounded by <script type="text/javascript"></script>?  Can you show your code so there's something to actually review?

Comment: I did already as you told me and put it before the /head in the header.php:

<script type="text/javascript">
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var href = links[i].href;
    if (href.startsWith("http://www.EXAMPLE.com"))
        links[i].href = "https://www.amazon.com//ref=EXAMPLE";
    }
</script>

EDIT: stackoverflow delete the http automatically but I used it of course

Comment: I think I see the problem - this script needs to execute after the links have been loaded, so it should actually go in the footer.php file just before the </body> tag.  In the head section it was running too soon, before there were links to modify.

Comment: YES, now it works! Thank you very much for your time and your help, I apprecciate that a lot! God bless you.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to use a WP plugin to rewrite/replace all of the URLs with the new one. This approach you will only need to rewrite them once and not have to worry about them in the future. Just be cautious.

Something like the [Search & Replace](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-and-replace/) plugin might do the trick, otherwise try [Search Regex](https://wordpress.org/plugins/search-regex/).